# Building jars with sbt

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm following this tutorial to create a scala jar to upload to streamsets to use in a spark evaluator.

I'm using Intellij 2017.3.4.

If I use Intellij to build the artifact into the out folder, it's over 100mb in size.

If i use the 'sbt clean package' option from the command line, the jar is 3mb.

They both work fine.

Could anyone tell me why there's such a difference, and how I'd setup my Intellij so I create the smaller version?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Without further knowledge of your `build.sbt` and your IntelliJ settings I can only guess that your `build.sbt` contains a line like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0" % Provided
```

Notice the `Provided`. It means that spark is not bundled in the jar that sbt prepares, but is expected to already be present at the server in which you run your program (on your class path).

IntelliJ uses all the jars (including those marked `provided`) so that you can debug/run your program via IntelliJ. Since you did not add your build settings in IntelliJ this is the best I can do for now.

If you use `sbt assembly` to package your artifact, and you want to do this with a run configuration in IntelliJ you can go to `Run/Debug Configurations`, click the `+` button, select `sbt task` and fill in `assembly` as the task.

Read more about packaging your spark app [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#bundling-your-applications-dependencies).

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi @dvir, thanks for getting back to me.  The build.sbt is defined in that web page I linked to, it doesn't have Provided in the lines.  As you may have worked out, this is all very new to me.  I'll have a look at the links you've provided, thanks again.

Comment: Ah, no link :-)  Here's the tutorial I'm following https://github.com/streamsets/tutorials/blob/master/tutorial-spark-transformer-scala/readme.md